# Updating Env variables in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

What's the best practice to update env. varaibles and re-deploy an existing service fabric application if the version is the same? It seems you can't update env variables on the fly. As well as you can re-deploy a service with the same version.

I don't want to force a new build to re-deploy this.

Comment: Is this a production system? If so, don't do this - you're basically neutering Service Fabric's ability to automatically protect you against configuration changes that break things.

Comment: If I want to change logging configurations which are environment variables, how else could I do this? I do not want to do a re-build.

Answer (score 1):

For just config changes, you can "Edit Manifest Versions.." and just update the config version of the service which has the config changes. It will also update the application manifest version itself if you do it from Visual Studio. So the application version is increased and should not have any issues in deployment regarding versions.

Comment: I'm not doing this in visual studio, the version is set during our build process. We have strict verification/compliance surrounding approving a build, so I want to be able to make config updates post-deployment without having to do a new build.

Comment: If you just want to change the config values(and not adding new config key value), you can just upgrade the application using powershell command Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade and provide parameters  using -ApplicationParameter and keeping the application type version same. This way the application is at the same version but with updated configuration values.